# Magento 2 replace a core javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, swatches

I was trying to replace magento 2 core javascript file for Swatches render which is located at `app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js` . And I followed official guide for this - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html , but it did not work.

I have uploaded my module on GIT. Can someone check and tell me what is the issue ? Here is the GIT Link for the module created - https://github.com/chamalC/magento-2-replace-javascript/tree/master/app/code/Muaw/CustomSwatches

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below code in your requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
     map: {
    '*': {
        swatchRenderer: 'Muaw_CustomSwatches/js/SwatchRenderer'
    }
}};
```

Comment: @Shaheer How would you do that in Magneto 2.1? File `SwatchRenderer.js` was renamed to `swatch-renderer.js`. But more important is that they removed `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` from the module. So `swatch-renderer.js` is not referenced there anymore.

Comment: @zitix did u get the soln ?

Comment: works in <= M2.0 but not 2.1, see below answer for 2.1

Answer (score 8):

The code works for me on Magento 2.1.5

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
           'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'Vendor_Module/js/swatch-renderer'     
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an Easy way out for that when you do that changes while creating a custom Theme,

Firstly override the template File in which the Js is being called i.e 
module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml
and change the line

```
"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"
```

to

`"Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer-custom"`

Secondly create a js file in web/js Directory named **swatch-renderer-custom.js**
Then if you apply any code in that js file then your code will be called....

Comment: only thing that works in 2.1.. but it should be noted that the `swatch-renderer-custom` can then extend `Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer` by adding that in the `define` + adding fotorama there

Answer (score 1):

Try below based on docs of magento 2 inside requirejs-config.js file,
You have to do below,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            swatchRenderer:'Magento_Swatches/js/SwatchRenderer'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Using Mixins:
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Ayasoftware_EnhancedConfigurable/js/swatches': true
            }
        }
    },
    }
};
```