# Magento 2 error in swatchRenderer.js at 'updateData' property

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

I have this error in category page. When i change color from swatch option it star loading in product image container and shows error in SwatchRenderer.js

here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).processUpdateBaseImage (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:1168:25)
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).processUpdateBaseImage (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).updateBaseImage (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:1137:22)
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).updateBaseImage (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._ProductMediaCallback (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:1103:18)
at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._ProductMediaCallback (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:402:25)
at Object.mediaSuccessCallback [as success] (http://127.0.0.1/magentoblank/pub/static/version1515737320/frontend/jtuser/customtheme/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:981:29)
at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27449)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213)
at y (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:22721)
```

i am using custom jquery.min file and created one custom slider with sly.js hope it will help you to understand my issue well.

TIA

Comment: Can you show us your custom js?

Comment: (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:22721)

this is the custom js i am talking about

Comment: Links broken for me

Comment: @leek I through seem that the issue came from the custom js. Is there any reason why you use the custom jquery min js?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106865/magento-2-error-in-swatchrenderer-js & https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177674/69 related possibly.

Comment: Please, try to remove jQuery.min instance, which you add and use default jquery...

Comment: What happened when you run console.log(jQuery('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').data('gallery')); in console like Ben Suggested?

Answer (score 7):

As I can't replicate this issue it's hard for me to say what the issue is exactly but following the code from the error it seems to be when `$('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').data('gallery')` is undefined. The cause of this is likely to be a class or data attribute being removed/changed.

To confirm this is the case when you replicate the problem paste this into your console:

```
console.log(jQuery('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').data('gallery'));
```

This is how the console log looks for me:
[image]

If undefined is returned then this is your problem.

## Debugging

To resolve this the first thing I'd do is check the following elements/selectors exist in the DOM. If they do not exist try finding where they are in the core and adding them back.

- `[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]`
- `.column.main`
- `.product-item-info`

I say this as following the code back from this error leads me to the following:

1. `gallery.updateData(imagesToUpdate);`
2. `mediaGallerySelector: '[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]'`
3. `this.updateBaseImage(images, $main, isProductViewExist);`
4. `$main = isProductViewExist ? $this.parents('.column.main') : $this.parents('.product-item-info')`

Another option could be that `data('gallery')` isn't being set, if that's the case the issue could be anything.

### Notes

It will help if you could include the version of Magento you are working on, and any customisations you have done around swatches and/or the gallery DOM and/or JS.

**A quick way to debug this could be to revert all the changes you've made to swatches/gallery and see if it works, if it does add the files back one by one until you find the one that caused the problem. Then run a diff on that file and go from there.**

Answer (score 3):

We had this same issue until we realized we were hiding the price of products on our category listing page. Apparently, `swatch-renderer.js` relies on classes on the price box to determine if it is on the product view or product listing page. After re-enabling the price box, color swatch switching started working again.

Comment: Great, was exactly I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty efficient way to fix this:

Copy the `/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`-file to `app/design/YourName/YourTheme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and replace the `updateBaseImage()` (line ~1152) with the following:

```
updateBaseImage: function (images, context, isInProductView, eventName) {
    var gallery = context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');

    if (eventName === undefined && gallery !== undefined) {
        this.processUpdateBaseImage(images, context, isInProductView, gallery);
    } else {
        context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).on('gallery:loaded', function (loadedGallery) {
            loadedGallery = context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');
            this.processUpdateBaseImage(images, context, isInProductView, loadedGallery);
        }.bind(this));
    }
},
```

You can also override the file using a module, but I found this to be the easiest way. There's plenty of information readily available to override a JS-component using a module.

It's weird that they define `gallery` and just assume it'll be defined afterwards. Adding a check for this fixes everything.

It works perfect! I just hope that the Magento Dev's pick up on this and implement this in the core-code.

Comment: This is not working for me since there is no `processUpdateBaseImage()` defined in `swatch-renderer.js`

Comment: @MohitRane might've been changed in recent Magento versions? When I have time I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
What happened is that i have created a container for product.media outside of .column.main.
Then the swatch-renderer.js was looking for that parent of product.media (.column.main), the solution was just changing the swatch-renderer.js lines that references to .column.main to my new container, product-container.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I select edit on view cart's page. On `updateBaseImage` after this line:

```
imagesToUpdate = this._setImageIndex(imagesToUpdate);
```

Replace:

```
this._updateGallery(gallery, imagesToUpdate, isInitial);
```

With:

```
 if (gallery) {
    this._updateGallery(gallery, imagesToUpdate, isInitial);
 } else {
    context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).on('gallery:loaded', function (loadedGallery) {
    gallery = context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');
        this._updateGallery(gallery, imagesToUpdate, isInitial);
    }.bind(this));
}


// Add this method. To avoid code duplication
_updateGallery: function (gallery, imagesToUpdate, isInitial) {
    gallery.updateData(imagesToUpdate);

    if (isInitial) {
        $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents();
    } else {
        $(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).AddFotoramaVideoEvents({
            selectedOption: this.getProduct(),
            dataMergeStrategy: this.options.gallerySwitchStrategy
        });
    }

    gallery.first();
},
```

The error happens because the swatcher expects the fotorama to be loaded. The `else` condition handles the first load, and the `if` handle the swatcher color change to update the carousel, since `gallery` is not `undefined` anymore.

This happens on catalog' views and product page

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing this issue than and resolve it in magento2.3.0.

First Check ***"column main"*** class Product view page source code if not found than remove your layout this location

```
app/design/frontend/YourName/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout
```

than this is working.